# Invalid method declartion required return type, Java controller method

Tags: java

I know that it may be a silly mistake but I am looking at this code for about 15 minutes and I cannot see nothing wrong. Besides I can continue to do my work with this error.

I have the following method

```
    GetMapping("/pagina/imoveis-residenciais-venda")
------------------------------------------------- (red marker of error)
    public List<Imovel> recuperarPaginaImoveisResidenciaisVenda(){
        List<Imovel> imoveis = this.imovelRepositorio.recuperarPaginaImoveisResidenciaisVenda();
        return imoveis;
    }
```

And the following error message, as `GetMapping` is underlined with the red marker:

```
    invalid method declaration, required return type
```

Comment: You need to start your `GetMapping` with an `@` sign like this `@GetMapping`

Comment: That's was difficult one to spot. I know that was silly, but was a difficult one to spot. "invalid method declaration, required return type?"

Comment: If you like Mahabubul Hasan's answer you may want to vote it up

Comment: Now that I thorught about it does make sense "return type required".  Without the "@" it would be a method GetMapping without return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetMapping is an annotation, and annotation must start with an @ sign so your code should look like this

```
@GetMapping("/pagina/imoveis-residenciais-venda")
public List<Imovel> recuperarPaginaImoveisResidenciaisVenda(){
     List<Imovel> imoveis = this.imovelRepositorio.recuperarPaginaImoveisResidenciaisVenda();
     return imoveis;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help. I think I would spend three more hours in this... and I am not kidding. "required return type".